# How to create a page template using custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, page-template

I am building a plugin. I just want to create page template whenever i install plugin. Page template like full-width template. I have used codes after searching but not able to get success.  So please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what code did you try?

Comment: If you say you tried something and don't show what, the risk is someone offering you the same solution as you already tried. Apart, just asking *"I want this, please help me"* is considered a work-for-me-for-free type of Question. I'm sure it's not your intention, but it translates like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to actually generate a page template when the plugin is activated, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Testtest
 * Description: Ignore
 * Version: 0.1
 * Author: windyjonas
 */
function myplugin_activate() {
    $buf = "<?php\n"
        . "/*\n"
        . " * Template Name: generated template\n"
        . " */\n"
        . "?>\n"
        . "Hello world\n";

    $handle = fopen( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/tpl-plugin.php', 'w' );
    fwrite( $handle, $buf );
    fclose( $handle );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
```

This only works if the web server user has enough privileges to write to theme directory.

Comment: This won't scale well... I use the technique from [this plugin](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/page-template-example/): copy the template from plugin folder to theme folder.

Comment: Won't scale? It is a one time operation! Doesn't matter if you write to file or copy a file.

Comment: I guess we mean different thing by "scale".... I'm referring to hundreds of lines with `.=` ?

Comment: Ah, ok, agreed, this should be seen more as a proof of concept, how the content is generated is up to the plugin author.